# volume of a block with known are of a square inside

Tags: volume

The task is to figure out the volume of a block ABCDEFGH . AB(EH ...) is x and BC(also FG...)is x + 23. The third side is unknown(AE, BF ...) The area of the rectangle BCEH is 4225.
[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMc4f.png)

Comment: Hi and Welcome Rudolf. Could you please let us know what you have tried so far? What is the context for your question?

Answer (score 0):

For a rectangular prism, we need to know the length, height, and depth to get the volume. We know the length is $ x $, and the height is $ x+23$. So for volume we have $$ V = x * (x+23) * depth $$
Now, we want to find the depth, which is $EA=FB=GC=HD$. We know the area of the rectangle is 4225. The area of a rectangle has the equation Area = length * height. To make sure we don't get these values confused let's call the $$ Area = length{_{r}} * height{_{r}}$$
The length of the rectangle ($ length{_{r}} $) is $ BC $ which we know to be x+23. The equation for the area is then $ 4225 = (x+23)*height{_{r}} $. Based on the sketch, $height{_{r}}$ is the hypotenuse of the right triangle $ EAB $. Let's rearrange the equation so we get the $height{_{r}}$ in terms of x: $$ \frac{4225}{x+23}=height{_{r}}$$ Remember, we are trying to find the depth to get the volume. The depth is equal to EA, which is the height of the right triangle EAB. Use the Pythagorean Theorem, $ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 $, to solve for the missing side:
$$ x^2 + b^2 = (\frac{4225}{x+23})^2 $$
$$ b^2 = (\frac{4225}{x+23})^2 - x^2 $$
$$ b = \sqrt{(\frac{4225}{x+23})^2 - x^2} $$
Plugging in everything in for the volume equation, we get the following:
$$ V = x * (x+23) * \sqrt{(\frac{4225}{x+23})^2 - x^2} $$

Comment: I am really glad for your help but is it possible to calculate the exact number ? Somehow create a system of equations with two unknowns ?